# Next.js 14 Sub-Domain Redirect

Tags: reactjs, next.js, subdomain, next.js14

I'm trying to add sub domain to my Next.js application to make dynamic domain pages.
For example: **sub.domain.com**.

I have tried to use **Redirect **function in the `next.config` file like this, but it's a bit tricky:

```
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "/",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Check out this guide on how to [build a multi-tenant page](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application). Please note that you should do some research on your own before posting to stack overflow. A simple google search would've probably sufficed.